# Unable to edit netbeans.conf

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

I am trying to modify *'netbeans.conf'* located at following path:

C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc

When i modify the file; add

```
-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

In Notepad, it is not allowing me to save the original file.

In Notepad++, it says *'please echeck if this file is opened in another program'*.

Netbeans is installed in path -> C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\

How can i modify the file? Is there any issue in privileges?

Comment: Do you have netbeans open?  Is there something else which has the file open?  Do you have the correct security permissions to modify files in the `Program Files` directory?

Comment: Only adminiistrators can modify files in C:\Program Files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

copy that file and paste in desktop edit what you want then paste into 
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\ location its works

Answer (score 9):

Close NetBeans, start notepad or another text editor as Administrator (right click on the application and choose "Run as administrator" and then open 'netbeans.conf' with it.